# Calculating distance - on the fly or as soon as data is entered into database?

Tags: java, mysql, google-maps, sorting

Working on a small web application, I have a user table in which user details is stored along with latitude and longitude of their current locations.

A new user registers, he is shown the distance of all the users from where he currently is.

I am doing it using the haversine formula.

My problem is how do I proceed on doing this?
How can I do this on the fly? Or do I need to calculate all the user distances when the user registers and save it?

Should cater for sorting: i.e shortest distance first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of users is going to be very large (or unbounded) then you may run into trouble.

Calculating this up-front might require quite a bit of storage. But calculating on demand might require a large amount of server CPU time.

Some considerations:

1. Use MySQL to do the geo-sorting. http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL
2. Consider calculating distances for only a small subset of other users.
3. Consider the benefits of having the distances calculated dynamically on the client machine using javascript.

Comment: can you point me to some tutorial or something that i can work on.

Comment: Others may disagree, but jQuery is perhaps a defacto standard for making javascript easy. http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials. Using jQuery, have your page make an async call to retrieve co-ords of the other users, then calculate and display the distances from the result - all processing done in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you're storing all the distances between all your users at the time of registration, you're going to find yourself very quickly storing a large amount of data - for 100 users, ~5,000 pieces of data. For 1000 users, ~500,000 (with relevant calculations required for each) - plus, if a user changes their location, that data will immediately become redundant, requiring a recalculation for all users. Again, a huge time issue with a lot of users.

You probably would be better off doing this on-the-fly - MySQL offers up spatial extensions which you can make use of to optimise location based searching (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html)

A very simple example using these extensions can be found at http://maisonbisson.com/blog/post/12147/working-with-spatial-data-in-mysql/ - more complex examples should allow you to return all points within a radius r.

Someone else mentioned calculating this on the client-side using Javascript. Certainly a possibility but again consider if you have a large number of users, say 10,000 - you'd have to transfer all that data to the client first (resulting in a delay for an HTTP fetch), then assume that they have a reasonably powerful CPU to run the calculations (what if someone's looking at your site on an old smartphone?). You could end up freezing their browser for a few seconds while the process runs.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answer say, you should use a geo-database.

If you want to implement it yourself, this is how those database do internally:

Divide the map into large rectanglar grids (say, 10km x 10km grid). For each user, add a column telling which grid he is in. Instead of searching all user, you can just search that particular grid and the 8 grids neighbor to it..